# Adjust the yAxis fontSize in highchart in R

Tags: r, highcharts

Is there a way to increase the `yAxis` labels in highcharts in R?

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_title(text = "some plot name") %>%
  hc_add_series(subset1_melted_nona,type = "scatter", hcaes(x = variable, y = value), value= 10, color="darkblue", name="freq", marker = list(radius = 2)) %>%
  hc_add_series(subset1_melted_nona, type = "arearange", hcaes(x=variable, low =errmin, high=errmax), yAxis=1, name="cov", color="red") %>%
  hc_add_series(subset1_melted_nona, type= "line", hcaes(x = variable, y = enb), yAxis=2, name="comp", color="#CC6600") %>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(lineWidth = 3, lineColor="darkblue",title=list(text="freq")),
    list(lineWidth = 3, opposite = TRUE, lineColor="red", title=list(text="cov")),
    list(lineWidth = 3, opposite = TRUE, lineColor="#CC6600", title=list(text="comp")))
```

Comment: Can you make this post reproducible by adding data? `dput(subset1_melted_nona)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS to edit labels from the available Highcharts JS API:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.style.fontSize

You can find an article on how to do this here:
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-highcharts-javascript-syntax-in-r/